# Getting real Excel cell type does not work for text cells having number (Java org.apache.poi library)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to obtain values from Excel sheet using org.apache.poi:poi:3.15 (and 3.9) libraries where I need to format cells having numbers (being formatted as Numbers in Excel) as Integers and having text (being formatted as Text in Excel) as Strings.

The trouble is when I have a cell being formatted as Text in Excel but containing value "1". While Excel knows it's a piece of text and formats that as text, I did not figure out how to learn it's Text formatted (and not a number) in Java. All methods the library gives me are formatting the value as a number.

`cell.getCellType()` returns `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`

`cell.getCellTypeEnum()` returns `CellType.NUMERIC`

`new DataFormatter().getDefaultFormat(cell)` returns `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ExcelGeneralNumberFormat`

`new DataFormatter().getFormat(cell)` returns `java.text.DecimalFormat`

Any idea?

Comment: Funny, I perhaps found the reason. IMHO, it's a defect in POI library. Once the cell is formatted as General, POI library will always say it has NUMERIC format if it includes a number. And POI will return NUMERIC format even when I change the format in Excel to Text. To fix this, I need to DELETE whole the row (or column) is Excel, properly format the cells first (into Text) and then enter the values (numbers). Only then, POI will identify such cells as having Text.

Comment: you can check the cells value with regex and format it depending on value

Comment: XtremeBaumer: the cell contains number but I want to format is as a String. How would regex help me?

Comment: Actually, by coincidence, I found also the opposite behavior. I had cells being formatted as General, having numbers and POI was returning them as String. I wanted POI to format them as Numbers but changing the format to Number in Excel did not help. I had to remove the whole column in Excel, add new Column, format it as Number and then enter the values. Only then POI was giving me it as Number format.

Comment: I think the moment you enter something which has only numbers into Excel, it considers it a number. It doesn't matter what format you choose for it. Try to create a column which multiplies this column by 1, and see what it does with the values which are numbers.

Comment: @pepan that is not what you ask in your question. maybe reword it to be clearer

Comment: RealSkeptic: Excel knows how to treat the values; once it's formatted as text, it treats that as text; once it's formatted as number, it treats that as number; once it's formatted as general, it tries to guess what the value is. The trouble is that POI does not follow the explicitly set format.

Comment: XtremeBaumer: is it now clearer? Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: @pepan as i understand your question, you iterate over all cells in that sheet and try to get the value in either a string or a int. what has the formatting to do with it? is your question about changing the formatting of the cells or retrieving the values?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I need to obtain the value either as Integer or as String depending on the original format the cell has in Excel

Comment: you can literally sh*t in the format and have a look at the value stored inside. if it equals only numbers you can parse as integer otherwise use string

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you dont' get me. The cell contains "1" but it's explicitly set as Text in Excel and I need to treat it as Text (String) in Java. Got it?

Comment: now i understand what you want. i think there is no way way to get it at 100% chance to be right. the ways you posted seem to be the ones to get the cell format. is there any other way you could handle it? like all values in 1 column are always strings or something like that?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this is not what the original question is about and I asked it as I would like to get 100% chance to be right (it's a machine, right?). BTW, I've already found a workaround (even though not perfect); see my very first two comments.